# Rest api returns undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, jquery-ajax

I am trying to get a random list item field from a sharepoint list. but the results return is undefined. The URL of the rest api is correct as i copy and past it directly to the browser it displays correct value.

Please see the code below

```
     window.myFunction = function() {
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 320);  
alert('myFunction triggerred' + randomNumber);
//var listRandomURl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Wealoffortune')/items(4)?$select=Title&amp;$top=1";
var listRandomURl = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/development2/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Wealoffortune')/items("+randomNumber+")/Actions";
alert(listRandomURl);

$.ajax({
   url: listRandomURl, 
   method: "GET",
   headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
   success: function (data) {
        alert(data.d.results);
   }
});
}


 
 fd.spRendered(function () {
 fd.control('Button1').onclick = "myFunction();";
});
```

Also i would like this to be shown in a label not in an alert how do i do that?

Comment: What is `/Actions` in your endpoint URL? Also, the item with ID equals to `randomNumber` should be present in list then only it will return the results.

Comment: Actions is a field, random number is present in the list as it will only generate less than 320 from the list which has 320 items). when I copy past the url from the alert(listRandomURl); directly to the web browser i am getting the results.

Comment: Try using this: `var listRandomURl = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/development2/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Wealoffortune')/items("+randomNumber+")?$select=Actions";`

Comment: Its still the same Ganesh

Comment: Be advised that list item IDs increment and never reduce, and _are not guaranteed to be contiguous_.  If, during the creation and set up of your list, any items were deleted, those list item IDs are no longer valid. E.g. if someone deleted what _was_ ID 5, the new order goes `...3, 4, 6, 7...`, _and_ even if the total number of list items is 320, the top ID would now be 321 (since there is a gap where 5 used to be).  List item IDs do not correlate with an indexer into the number of list items in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST API endpoint `/items(<itemId>)` returns the list item data in `data.d` and not in `data.d.results`.

So, try changing your `success` function like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.d);
}
```

Here's working example where I am fetching `Title` of list item and showing it in label on DOM:

```
<p> Title:
    <label id="lblActions"></label>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, 1);
    });

    function getListItem(url, itemId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items(" + itemId + ")?$select=Title",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.d) {
                    $("#lblActions").text(data.d.Title);
                } else {
                    $("#lblActions").text("Item not found!");
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Good point!  I missed seeing that! :)

Comment: Thanks but now it says "[object Object]". Here is the full URL ,https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/development2/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Wealoffortune')/items(307)?$select=Actions and the output i get when past it in the browser and hit enter {"d":{"__metadata":{"id":"200f69c9-4717-422a-aaa6-dd4a4ba88dc6","uri":"https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/development2/_api/Web/Lists(guid'deb20c24-b7ef-456f-8d67-e2aa36b0e929')/Items(307)","etag":"\"1\"","type":"SP.Data.WealoffortuneListItem"},"Actions":"Share a chocolate covered anything treat with others today"}}

Comment: You can get `Actions` property by using `data.d.Actions`. Refer code in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, Its working thanks

Comment: @Rinu, do you also use range (with first and last ID) in your code? Because, if you get aleatory number out of the range of ID, this will break de code...

Answer (score 0):

Please, define a range of `randomNumber` variable, corresponding with the first ID number and last ID number of your list items. MDN Web Docs contains a good example to extract a integer number between min and max range:

```
//Example extracted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);

  //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 
}
```

Then, refactoring your approach, will be like this:

```
window.myFunction = function(min, max) {
 var randomNumber = getRandomInt(min,max);  
alert('myFunction triggerred' + randomNumber);
//var listRandomURl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Wealoffortune')/items(4)?$select=Title&amp;$top=1";
var listRandomURl = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/development2/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Wealoffortune')/items("+randomNumber+")/Actions";
alert(listRandomURl);

$.ajax({
   url: listRandomURl, 
   method: "GET",
   headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
   success: function (data) {
        alert(data.d.results);
   }
});
}


 
 fd.spRendered(function () {
 fd.control('Button1').onclick = "myFunction();";
});
```

Comment: I have updated the code with the above the results are stilll undefined.

Comment: @Rinu, please, what is "Actions" at last of URL? if "Actions" is a field, needs to update the URL to be like this:

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/development2/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Wealoffortune')/items("+randomNumber+")?$select=Actions; 

Is it possible to clear about "Actions"? And your JavaScript code inner in same sharePoint site URL?

Comment: Yes Actions is a field the I have tried both the below URL 1)https://keoic.sharepoint.com/sites/development2/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Wealoffortune')/items("+randomNumber+")?$select=Actions and 2) https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/development2/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Wealoffortune')/items("+randomNumber+")/Actions in both cases it results in the same error.  i am open to have other solutions using Java scripts as well